Determine the maximum content size for a box such as a modal dialog
For a personal project, I try to write as much of my own code as possible, minimizing the use of libraries. I have a dialog box which contains an image and an arbitrary number of other elements that appear above, below, to the side of, or partially overlapping the image. I want to know the maximum size the image can be such that no part of the dialog overflows the viewport.
As I struggled to think of how to approach this issue, I spent considerable time prompting several different AIs. The final code I came up with was initially written by AI and significantly fixed by me. It works now, but it is quite ugly and hard to follow.
Is there any way to simplify the code and/or use a better approach? It seems like a nightmare to change months from now, and it also seems like it's doing way too much.
/**
 * Calculates the maximum dimensions for a content element within a specified ancestor element.
 *
 * @param content - The content element for which to calculate the maximum dimensions.
 * @param ancestor - The ancestor element within which the content element is contained.
 * @param extra_margin - The extra margin to subtract from the available viewport dimensions. Defaults to 10.
 * @param minimum_dimension - The minimum dimension that the content element can have. Defaults to 50.
 * @returns The maximum width and height that the content element can have.
 */
export function maximum_content_size(content: HTMLElement, ancestor: HTMLElement, extra_margin: number = 10, minimum_dimension: number = 50): Dimensions {
  // Get dimensions of the viewport
  const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  // Initialize total padding and dimensions of intermediate elements and their siblings
  let totalPaddingWidth = 0;
  let totalPaddingHeight = 0;
  let otherElementsWidth = 0;
  let otherElementsHeight = 0;

  // Traverse from content up to ancestor
  let currentElement: Nullable<HTMLElement> = content;
  while (currentElement && currentElement !== ancestor) {
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(currentElement);
    totalPaddingWidth += parseFloat(styles.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(styles.paddingRight);
    totalPaddingHeight += parseFloat(styles.paddingTop) + parseFloat(styles.paddingBottom);

    // Accumulate dimensions of siblings
    const parentElement: Nullable<HTMLElement> = currentElement.parentElement;
    if (parentElement) {
      const contentRect = content.getBoundingClientRect();
      Array.from(parentElement.children).forEach(sibling => {
        if (sibling !== currentElement) {

          // Determine positions of sibling and content elements
          const siblingRect = sibling.getBoundingClientRect();
          if (siblingRect.bottom <= contentRect.top || siblingRect.top >= contentRect.bottom) {
            // Sibling is above or below content
            otherElementsHeight += siblingRect.height;
          } else if (siblingRect.right <= contentRect.left || siblingRect.left >= contentRect.right) {
            // Sibling is to the left or right of content
            otherElementsWidth = Math.max(otherElementsWidth, siblingRect.width);
          } else {
            // Sibling partially overlaps content
            let nonOverlapWidth = 0;
            let nonOverlapHeight = 0;
            if(siblingRect.left < contentRect.left && siblingRect.right > contentRect.left && siblingRect.right < contentRect.right) {
              // Sibling overlaps content on the left
              nonOverlapWidth = contentRect.left - siblingRect.left;
            } else if(siblingRect.right > contentRect.right && siblingRect.left > contentRect.left && siblingRect.left < contentRect.right) {
              // Sibling overlaps content on the right
              nonOverlapWidth = siblingRect.right - contentRect.right;
            }
            if(siblingRect.top < contentRect.top && siblingRect.bottom > contentRect.top && siblingRect.bottom < contentRect.bottom) {
              // Sibling overlaps content on the top
              nonOverlapHeight = contentRect.top - siblingRect.top;
            } else if(siblingRect.bottom > contentRect.bottom && siblingRect.top > contentRect.top && siblingRect.top < contentRect.bottom) {
              // Sibling overlaps content on the bottom
              nonOverlapHeight = siblingRect.bottom - contentRect.bottom;
            }
            if (nonOverlapWidth > 0) {
              if (contentRect.top <= siblingRect.top && contentRect.bottom >= siblingRect.bottom) {
                // Content is fully contained within sibling vertically
                otherElementsWidth += nonOverlapWidth;
              } // FIXME: doesn't account for content being partially contained within sibling vertically
            }
            if (nonOverlapHeight > 0) {
              if (contentRect.left <= siblingRect.left && contentRect.right >= siblingRect.right) {
                // Content is fully contained within sibling horizontally
                otherElementsHeight += nonOverlapHeight;
              } // FIXME: doesn't account for content being partially contained within sibling horizontally
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }

    currentElement = parentElement;
  }

  // Calculate the maximum dimensions for the content element
  const maxWidth = viewportWidth - totalPaddingWidth - otherElementsWidth - extra_margin;
  const maxHeight = viewportHeight - totalPaddingHeight - otherElementsHeight - extra_margin;

  return {
    width: Math.max(maxWidth, minimum_dimension),
    height: Math.max(maxHeight, minimum_dimension)
  };
}

